# create magento 1.8 custom module

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have to write a custom login module for magento 1.8, I'm new to magento and after googling I found [this tutorial](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller), but there is a big problem
After creating module when I want to load my own page, 404  error occurs
I can't found anything on magento documentations, please help

Here is my code:

/app/code/local/Test/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<config>     
    <modules> 
        <Test_Mymodule> 
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </Test_Mymodule> 
    </modules> 
     <!-- This node contains parameters, available on frontend --> 
    <frontend> 
        <!-- Module aliases are located in this block --> 
        <routers> 
            <!-- This node's name should be the same as our alias --> 
            <mymodule> 
                <!-- use parameter specifies which of basic routers needs to be used. 
                This can be "standard" for frontend or "admin" for backend --> 
                <use>standard</use> 
                <!-- router arguments block --> 
                <args> 
                    <!-- This parameter specifies the full name of out module --> 
                    <module>Test_Mymodule</module> 
                    <!-- This parameter sets module alias --> 
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName> 
                </args> 
            </mymodule> 
        </routers> 
      <layout> 
            <updates>                
                <helloworld>                     
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file> 
                </helloworld> 
            </updates> 
        </layout> 
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

/app/etc/modules/Test_Mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<config>     
    <modules> 
        <Test_Mymodule> 
           <active>true</active> 
           <codePool>local</codePool> 
        </Test_Mymodule> 
    </modules> 
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Test/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Test_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{ 

   public function indexAction() 
    { 
     echo "test"; 
    } 
}
```

[image: 404 page :(]

Comment: Did you turn off the cache management?

Comment: yes cache management is off

Comment: then you have to paste your code...

Comment: where I paste my code? I turned cache off before I start to write module and after that module name shows in configuration, but don't work

Comment: @ZvonimirBurić I paste my code in question

Comment: and the url you are trying to load is example.com/mymodule/index/index ?

Comment: Yes I tried it and /mymodule & /mymodule/index, all goes 404

Comment: Then just delete the `var/cache` folder in your Magento root folder. I don't have any other idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found where is the problem, the whole problem is about case-sensitive words in xml files
my problem is solved simply by replacing `<mymodule>` by `<Mymodule>` in `config.xml` file and the final `config.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<config>     
    <modules> 
        <Test_Mymodule> 
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </Test_Mymodule> 
    </modules> 
     <!-- This node contains parameters, available on frontend --> 
    <frontend> 
        <!-- Module aliases are located in this block --> 
        <routers> 
            <!-- This node's name should be the same as our alias --> 
            <Mymodule> 
                <!-- use parameter specifies which of basic routers needs to be used. 
                This can be "standard" for frontend or "admin" for backend --> 
                <use>standard</use> 
                <!-- router arguments block --> 
                <args> 
                    <!-- This parameter specifies the full name of out module --> 
                    <module>Test_Mymodule</module> 
                    <!-- This parameter sets module alias --> 
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName> 
                </args> 
            </Mymodule> 
        </routers> 
      <layout> 
            <updates>                
                <helloworld>                     
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file> 
                </helloworld> 
            </updates> 
        </layout> 
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

I really hate magento xml configurations

Thx to Zvonimir

Comment: how much time does it take to realize this ?

Comment: @Chester about 6 days

Comment: I know that feeling :)